# Passing object (with KeyValuePair) back into controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, key-value

I have tried looking around for an answer to this, but I have been stuck for the better part of a day, so I thought the good people here may be able to help me!

I have a list of Monitor objects that I list on the index page. Each monitor has more information to show on the details page. The problem I am having is with the

```
public List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> FaxcomMonitorData { get; set; }
```

shown below.

Monitor Class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Monitor
{
    [DataMember]
    public string MonitorType { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string AtlasMonitorHeader { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string AtlasMonitorData { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> FaxcomMonitorData { get; set; }

    (...other attributes here...)

}
```

Monitors can be of 2 types: ATLAS and FAXCOM. Depending on which they are, the respective data attribute will be updated with appropriate values and the other is left null. (ie Atlas has AtlasMonitorHeader and Data are not null but FaxcomMonitorData is null)

Index ActionResult:

```
public ActionResult Index() 
    {
        MonitorServiceClient client = null;
        List<Monitor> monitors = null;
        try
        {
            client = new MonitorServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IMonitorService");
            monitors = new List<Monitor>(client.GetMonitors());
            if (monitors.Any(x => x.Status.Equals("red")))
                ViewData["OverallStatus"] = "red";
            else
                ViewData["OverallStatus"] = "green";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (null != client)
                client.Abort();
        }
        return View(monitors);
    }
```

When the list of monitors comes in here the monitors in the list look great! The KeyValuePair has the correct values and all is good.

Index View:

```
<div id="overallstatus">
    <table style="border-style:none">
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align:middle; font-size:30px; color:Black; border-style:none" >Overall Status:</td>
            <td style="border-style:none" >
                <% if (ViewData["OverallStatus"].Equals("red")) { %>
                    <img src="../../../Content/Images/RedStoplightRG.png" alt="" height="60px" width="140px"/>
                <% } %>
                <% else if (ViewData["OverallStatus"].Equals("green")) { %>
                    <img src="../../../Content/Images/GreenStoplightRG.png" alt="" height="60px" width="140px"/>
                <% } %>
            </td>
        </tr> 
    </table>
</div>

<br />
<br />

<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>
            Monitor
        </th>
        <th>
            Current Status
        </th>
        <th>
            Last Update
        </th>
    </tr>

<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", item)%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: item.MonitorName %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <% if (item.Status.Equals("green")) { %>
                <img alt="" src="../../../Content/Images/GreenStoplightRG.png" height="40px" width="95px"/> 
            <% } %>
            <%-- <% else if (Model.CurrentStatus.Equals("red")) { %>
                <img alt="" src="../../../Content/Images/RedStoplightRG.png" />
            <% } %> --%>
            <% else { %>
                <img alt="" src="../../../Content/Images/RedStoplightRG.png" height="40px" width="95px"/>
            <% } %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: String.Format("{0:g}", item.LastUpdated) %>
        </td>
    </tr>

<% } %>

</table>
```

The bottom table here displays each monitor and some data. When I click the details hyperlink I go to this controller method.

Details ActionResult:

```
public ActionResult Details(Monitor monitor)
    {
        if (monitor.MonitorType.Equals("ATLAS"))
            return RedirectToAction("AtlasDetails", monitor);
        if (monitor.MonitorType.Equals("FAXCOM"))
            return RedirectToAction("FaxcomDetails", monitor);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

If I click on a monitor of type ATLAS (that do not have the KeyValuePair), all the attributes are just fine.

FAXCOM types though have most of the attributes set correctly, except for the KeyValuePair. It is null now, even though it wasn't when the object was initially received (in the Index ActionResult).

I don't believe I am doing anything to cause the KeyValuePair to go null in the view, but I haven't used it before so I may need to pass the information in a different way that I am right now.

Let me know if additional code or explanation will help. Thank you!

Edit: I am not using a database at all and the service I consume in the Index page only will give me the a list of Monitor objects. I would prefer not to call (and wait for) the service again since it would take a long time if there are many monitors.

Edit:
Thanks to fan711's explanation of why what we were trying wasn't going to work, we decided to go with a different (somewhat ugly) workaround due to time constraints. If you have more time, you should go with Jonathan's answer and follow those good coding practices if possible. I thought I would at least post here what we did in case someone else wants to use it.

We ended up making the FaxcomMonitorData a string that was delimited by commas and carrots (, and ^) to separate the key from its value and keyvalues from other keyvalues. We then parsed this string and stored the data in a List>.

```
List<KeyValuePair<int,int>> FaxcomData = new List<KeyValuePair<int,int>>();

        List<string> keyvaluepairs = monitor.FaxcomMonitorData.Split('^').ToList();
        foreach (var pair in keyvaluepairs)
        {
            List<string> stringData = pair.Split(',').ToList();
            FaxcomData.Add(new KeyValuePair<int,int>(Convert.ToInt32(stringData[0]), Convert.ToInt32(stringData[1])));
        }
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing through the whole "monitor" object, maybe it would be better to pass through an Id, and rebuild the object in the Details action?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by this. Is your suggestion like how you would search a database using the Id (primary key) to get the object again? I don't have a database, and the service I am consuming only gives me the whole list of monitors. I can't use an Id to search for a specific object unless I had the list. I won't have access to the list unless I access the service again, but I would prefer to only do that when populated the list on the Index page. Does that make sense?

Comment: I didn't actually go with this option but I believe it is the best option for people who have more time to rework their program than I have. I will make sure to implement these coding practices in the future.

Comment: If the service call is expensive, you should cache it somewhere and then continue with this approach against the cached data. Does the data change very often? If not, you can make an initial service call in application start and either store in local db (or file system), or in server cache (carefully!). If data changes with some frequency, would also have to expire your cache with some frequency (every 10 minutes or whatever)

Answer (score 1):

The third argument to ActionLink() is in your case RouteValues. You can not pass a complex object to this parameter; it rather is a key/value collection of route values. You can see in the resulting html of your first view that .ToString is returned on each property of your item-object.

As Jonathan said, the preferred method would be to reload the monitor object from your service. If this isn't possible you may want to wrap the whole object in a form and pass each property as a hidden field. Something like:

```
<% for (item = 0; item<Model.Count; item++) { %>
    <% using(Html.BeginForm("Details",Nothing, FormMethod.Post)) { %>
        <%= Html.HiddenFor(m => m(item).MonitorType) %>
        <%= Html.HiddenFor(m => m(item).AtlasMonitor) %>
        <%= Html.HiddenFor(m => m(item).AtlasMonitorData) %>
        <% for (var i = 0; i<item.FaxcomMonitorData.Count; i++) { %>
            <% Html.HiddenFor(Function(m) m(item).Data(i).Key) %>
            <% Html.HiddenFor(Function(m) m(item).Data(i).Value) %>
        <% } %>
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    <% } %>
<% } %>
```

You might though need to put the item in a partial view (didn't test this code). This may sound complicate but MVC isn't designed to pass objects from controller action to controller action.

Another solution I could think of is to store the monitor items in the session state. Then pass only the index to the 'Details' action method. There retrieve it back from the session state. This of course would add state which is often not recommended either.

Comment: Ok. I will try this soon and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I never had a chance to implement your code, but your response helped me greatly in explaining the problem I was having to my boss. We ended up going with a different work-around (edited in question), but without your response I would have had a difficult time convincing him it wasn't going to be possible to do it the way we were planning. I'm going to mark Jonathan's answer as correct since it is the preferred method (it just wasn't an option in my case). Thanks!

Comment: If there is a way I can also mark yours as an answer or suggest that it was helpful (beyond the +1), please let me know.

Comment: There isn't but it's ok. I'm glad I could help